# jquery hide or show dynamic li of ul when click on li

Tags: php, jquery

In php while loop i got this type of data and when i click on li which id="test1" then hide that li which id="test1" and show li which id="new_test1"
i want to for particular ul means i click "li" then do process for that particular ul in which that li is present.

```
<ul id="cpvote">
<li id="test1">Message 1</span></li>
<li id="test2">Message 2</li>
<li id="test3">Message 3</li>
<li id="new_test1" style="display:none">Message 4</li>
<li id="new_test2" style="display:none">Message 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="cpvote">
<li id="test1">Message 1</span></li>
<li id="test2">Message 2</li>
<li id="test3">Message 3</li>
<li id="new_test1" style="display:none">Message 4</li>
<li id="new_test2" style="display:none">Message 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="cpvote">
<li id="test1">Message 1</span></li>
<li id="test2">Message 2</li>
<li id="test3">Message 3</li>

<li id="new_test1" style="display:none">Message 4</li>
<li id="new_test2" style="display:none">Message 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: id `id="cpvote"` must be unique with in elements

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: Shouldn't all ids be unique?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid or he can use child selector. Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: actually i got all ul in while loop so all ul id is same......so it's not possible to give unique id to all ul....

Comment: Use class instead of IDs. Learn to use class selector. Also show your jQuery code.

Comment: satpal class is same as id ,......bcz all thing i get in while loop dyanamically so that if give class then in output i got same class name

Comment: Mahi, IDs must be unique. However you can use a class multiple times. So you can easily use it.

Comment: "*actually i got all ul in while loop so all ul id is same*" - then you're doing it wrong, and producing invalid html.

Answer (score 1):

**IDs must be unique.** However you can use a class multiple times.

Use [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). Following is just an example to achieve desired result using class selector

*HTML*:

```
<ul class="cpvote">
    <li class="test1">Message 1</li>
    <li class="new_test1" style="display:none">Message 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="cpvote">
    <li class="test1">Message 1</li>
    <li class="new_test1" style="display:none">Message 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="cpvote">
    <li class="test1">Message 1</li>
    <li class="new_test1" style="display:none">Message 4</li>
</ul>
```

*Script*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.cpvote .test1', function () {
        $(this).closest('.cpvote').find('.new_test1').toggle();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vk180a/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this.

by using Jquery make UL Unique Identified

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // putting extra unique attributes in UL to Identified.

    $("UL").each(function(i){
        $("UL").eq(i).attr('ul-id','ul-'+i);    
    });

    $("UL").each(function(i){
        $("UL[ul-id='ul-"+i+"']").find("LI").on("click",function(){
           $("UL[ul-id='ul-"+i+"']").find("#new_"+$(this).attr('id')).show();
        });
    });
});
```

DEMO : [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/eethehgc/2/)